# How to find all elements in a page

Tags: javascript

I know of two ways to find all the elements in the page.

`document.getElementsByTagName('*')` and `document.all`

Is there a better way or is one of these the best?

I'm making an element selector (mostly for practice) and I want to know the most reliable way to get all of the elements in the page, to test against the selector.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`document.all` is an outdated proprietary method from Microsoft. Don't use it.

`document.getElementsByTagName('*')` is the W3C standard method of finding all the elements ina document - and surely the fastest - and works in Internet Explorer as well.

**P.S.** As someone is bound to chime in and provide a jQuery answer to this question, there's how to select all elements in a page using jQuery: `jQuery('*');`

:-)