# Javascript: How to make an array of every element in the page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to obtain an array of every element in a HTML page:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll("");
```

But no success.

Ideas?

thanks

Comment: If you were going to use `querySelectorAll()` which isn't the best way to do this, you would pass the selector `'*'` like this: `querySelectorAll('*')`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Unfortunately, `querySelectorAll` return a `NodeList`, not an `HTMLCollection`. This means that it's not a live collection, like `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346261/how-to-find-all-elements-in-a-page

Comment: @MaxArt - where in the OP's question does it say that the OP wants/needs a live collection?

Comment: @jfriend00 Because the OP wants an "array of every element", while `querySelectorAll` returns a _snapshot_ of the collection of every element. The difference may be subtle, and maybe silviolor actually wants a snapshot, but it's usually preferable to have a live collection, expecially in this case. You can store it and the it's  faster than calling `querySelectorAll` every time you need an updated array.

Comment: @MaxArt - it really depends upon what the OP really wants to do with it which they don't specify.  You are jumping to conclusions about what is best without having any relevant facts.  Live collections can be a total pain if you're trying to iterate through them while making changes to the DOM or if you only want to do a one-time operation.  They can also be a lot slower to use.  They can be very useful in other circumstances.  It all depends.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've already clarified myself. I stand the fact that there's hardly a point of not having a live collection of all the elements, unless you add elements while you iterate through it. AS for the performances, I hope you're kidding: http://jsperf.com/getelementsbytagname-vs-queryselectorall-all-elements http://jsperf.com/getelementsbytagname-vs-queryselectorall `getElementsByTagName` is **much** faster.

Comment: @MaxArt - I was speaking of the speed of iteration.  Iterating a live nodelist is often slower than iterating a static array.  See http://jsperf.com/getelementsbytagname-vs-queryselectorall/5 for info.

Comment: @jfriend00 No, honestly, who'd code like that? :D The first thing to do is to store the indexed item in a variable, in both cases. Anyway, I'd choose a static node list too in some cases, but I think the collection of every node isn't one, so a live collection would be perfect. And faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Comment: If you use JQuery, you can do `$('*')`, which has the same effect.

Comment: Faster to type, but a bit slower to run, since it has to parse the selector. Anyway, one can define `document.all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");` right at the beginning of the script.